# Select first 4 children (same attributes) of the parent node

Tags: xpath

How to select the first 4 children(same attributes) of the parent node having more than 3 children that also have the same attributes from the one, I want to select ?

I have tried this code but, its not working :-

```
//div[@class='content-page minified']/*[self::h2 or p[:2]]
```

My code:

```
<div class = "content-page minified">
   <h2> Company Description </h2>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <h2> Mission Description</h2>
   <p>...</p>
   <ul>...</ul>
   <p>...</p>
   <h2>Requirements</hs>
   <ul>...</ul>
   <a class="my child class" href="#">...</a>
   <div class="my second child class" href="#">...</div>
</div>
```

I expect to select both `<h2>` and first 3 `<p>` tags.

Comment: You have 3 `<h2>` tags, not two. What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks Jack, the exactly output is to select only first <h2> tag (<h2>Company Description</h2>) not the other ones, and select it together with the following two <p> tags.

Comment: @Jack thanks a-lot for your patience and time, it means a-lot, could you please double check wheter they is no syntax error, because when I'm checking it on my terminal, it says ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in (<--Xpath -->).

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact expression that raises the error?

Comment: File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1586, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //div[@class='content-page minified']/*[./name()='h2'][position()= 1 to 2]
>>>

Comment: That's because lxml only supports xpath 1.0, unfortunately. See edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first two `<p>` tags after the first `<h2>` tag, using lxml, try

```
import lxml.html
str = """
<div class = "content-page minified">
   <h2> Company Description </h2>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <h2> Mission Description</h2>
   <p>...</p>
   <ul>...</ul>
   <p>...</p>
   <h2>Requirements</hs>
   <ul>...</ul>
   <a class="my child class" href="#">...</a>
   <div class="my second child class" href="#">...</div>
</div>

"""

h= tree.xpath("//div[@class='content-page minified']/*['h2'][1]/following-sibling::p[position()<3]")
```

Comment: wow, You are really a genius @Jack, this is exactly what I was looking for :). Would you recommend me some nice xpath online tutorials.

Comment: @GivensonMwandla - Thanks, but I seriously doubt I'm anything close to a genius...Anyway, there are quite a few tutorials around, but one to start you off is here: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/10/27/an-introduction-to-xpath-with-examples. In addition, once you get to a decent level, you should get a book of a guy who is real genius (and an active SOer - Michael Kay): https://www.amazon.com/XSLT-2-0-XPath-Programmers-Reference/dp/0470192747.